# Is there a way to call a function once MapView.animateToRegion method stops

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

Im having an issue with my animateToRegion method which should zoom into a specific marker getting cut off during animation due to other functions being called (or at least thats my assumption).

Marker Component on MapView

```
<Marker
  key={index}
  ref={ref => (markers[index] = ref)}
  coordinate={{
    longitude: place.coordinates.lng,
    latitude: place.coordinates.lat
  }}
  onPress={() => {
    focusMarker(userRegion, place);
  }}
/>
```

The focusMarker function being called:

```
  //Zoom on Marker Function
  focusMarker = (userRegion, place) => {
    mapRef.current.animateToRegion({
      latitude: vendor.coordinates.lat,
      longitude: vendor.coordinates.lng,
      latitudeDelta: 0.005,
      longitudeDelta: 0.005
    });

onPressEvents(userRegion, place);
```

};

My onPressEvents function works as intended.  When I try and render this, my animation starts when pressing on a marker but cuts off or stutters and doesnt zoom in as intended.

If I comment out the onPressEvents function call, it works as intended.  The map centers and zooms in to the marker.

Is there a way to wait for the animation of animateToRegion to complete before calling the onPress function?  Im trying to avoid using setTimeOuts.  Is there an animation stop method I can call or when the animation stops, then call the function?

I have a main Class component which calls some outside functions that render my MapView and Marker when called.  This issue doesn't seem to happen when I create the MapView and Marker within the class component's render method.

Thanks

Comment: Update:  I changed when the focusMarker is called.  So for the marker OnPress, I set it to the OnPressEvents function which then runs and then calls the focusMarker.  The only issue is it works but its not a smooth transition.  It looks like the map recenters to its default latitudeDelta and longitudeDelta and then activates the focusMarker function which zooms in.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a bug.  I adjusted the state in the main component and passed it as a prop to my outside functions which rendered the mapview and marker components.  It seems to work now without the hitch and re-zoom.  I think my ref for MapView kept getting re-initialized and therefore keeping the __reactInternalSnapShotBEforeUpdate prop in the mapRef object pointing to the original region coordinates.  My functions kept thinking I wanted to create a new MapView reference object rather than work on the existing object that was already generated when the screen first rendered.